# Vue.js remove contenteditable attribute in render function

Tags: vue.js, vue-render-function

it seems should be a simple solution but something went wrong...

I need to conditionally **remove** `contenteditable` attribute from element:

```html
<!-- first state -->
<div contenteditable="true"></div>

<!-- second state -->
<div></div>
```

I've tried:

```js
data() {
    return {
      contenteditable: true,
      title: "Title",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    handleClick() {
      this.contenteditable = null;
      this.title = null;
    },
  },
  render(createElement) {
    const options = {
      attrs: {
        id: "ID",
        title: this.title,
        contenteditable: this.contenteditable,
        // Not working either
        //...(this.contenteditable && { contenteditable: true }),
      },
      domProps: {
        innerHTML: "<p>Test</p>",
      },
      on: {
        click: this.handleClick,
      },
    };

    return createElement("div", options);
  },
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-haze-dnvco?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue)

Result is: `<div contenteditable="false"></div>`, but I need to remove attribute completely. For example `title` attribute works as expected, it not renders if it's value was set to null. I've also tried to make `attrs` object fully reactive, like:

```js
data() {
  return {
    attrs: {
      title: 'Title',
      contenteditable: true,
    }
  }
},
methods: {
  handleClick() {
    Vue.delete(this.attrs, 'contenteditable')
    Vue.delete(this.attrs, 'title')
  },
},
render(createElement) {
    const options = {
      attrs: this.attrs,
      domProps: {
        innerHTML: "<p>Test</p>",
      },
      on: {
        click: this.handleClick,
      },
    };

    return createElement("div", options);
  },
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-bohr-ciywl?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue)

...but with no luck. Any ideas how to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue 2 treats the `contenteditable` attribute as a [special case](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/0603ff695d2f41286239298210113cbe2b209e28/src/platforms/web/runtime/modules/attrs.js#L55) here, it will not remove the attribute if the new attribute value is `undefined`. This is [fixed](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/8731#issuecomment-471251071) (or planned) in Vue 3.

You can bypass this behavior and set it with `domProps` instead:

```js
domProps: {
  contentEditable: this.contenteditable ? 'true' : 'inherit'
}
```

Here is a demo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      contenteditable: false
    }
  },
  render(h) {
    return h('div', [
      h('button', {
        on: {
          click: () => this.contenteditable = !this.contenteditable
        }
      }, `contenteditable: ${this.contenteditable}`),
      h('div', {
        domProps: {
          contentEditable: this.contenteditable ? 'true' : 'inherit'
        }
      }, 'Text')
    ])
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
</div>
```

Comment: Nope, result is the same `contenteditable=false`. It works fine with common attributes but not with `contenteditable`

Comment: I've updated my answer with a demo, inspect the DOM to verify the attribute is/isn't present.

Comment: I took a look at your codesandbox and discovered Vue has special behavior when *updating* the `contenteditable` attribute (which is why my suggestion only works when setting the attribute initially; it won't be removed in subsequent updates).

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, I've solved this with `this.$el.removeAttribute('contenteditable')` for deletion and `this.contenteditable = true` to set it back. It looks like not Vue.js way, but `contenteditable` is really special attribute, so, just need to keep it in mind.

Comment: Why are you messing with the DOM manually? My updated answer solves the problem correctly without resorting to DOM hacks.

Comment: Oh, I didn’t notice that you changed `attrs` to `domProps` in updated answer. Yeah, it did the trick in much cleaner way. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assume that your div is as below

```
<div id="editable"></div>
```

then you toggle contenteditable using the below approach

```
document.getElementById('editable').contentEditable = "true"
```

OR

```
document.getElementById('editable').setAttribute('contentEditable',"true")
```

If you want this div to be contentEditable at the begining then add the above line inside `mounted`.